# Do a CompletionStage inside a CompletionStage

Tags: java, completable-future, ebean, completion-stage

We have an internal API that executes the code in a lambda and returns a Boolean result in a CompleteStage:

```
private CompletionStage<Boolean> foo1() {
    return internalAPI(param -> {
        // first step
        // second step
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    });
}
```

Now the second step is implemented as an async task as well:

```
private CompletionStage<Boolean> foo2() {
    return internalAPI(param -> {
        // first step
        secondStep();  // <-- how to execute this and get result of it?
        // if second step finished successfully then ... 
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    });
}

private CompletionStage<Boolean> secondStep() {
    // do something
}
```

How do I make the `secondStep()` run in the `foo2()`, make sure it's finished before hitting `return Boolean.TRUE;`?

--- EDIT ---

This is the brief implementation of `internalAPI()`, basically it's trying to do all steps in one transaction and if one of the steps is failed the transaction can be rollback:

```
public <A> CompletableFuture<A> internalAPI(Function<Connection, A> block) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doTransaction(block),
            new HttpExecutionContext(databaseContext).current());
}

public <T> T doTransaction(Function<Connection, T> block) {
    Transaction tx = Ebean.beginTransaction();
    try (Connection sql2oConnection = sql.open()) {
        spliceConnections(sql2oConnection, tx.getConnection());
        T ret = block.apply(sql2oConnection);
        Ebean.commitTransaction();
        return ret;
    } finally {
        Ebean.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is going to depend on `internalAPI`, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: (It looks like `internalAPI` fundamentally expects a Function, to which the answer is "this is impossible." You can probably chain it with other CompletionStages, but that'll require going outside whatever internalAPI does; there isn't a generic way to do this.

Comment: What about just doing "first step" inside the function passed to `internalAPI`, then executing `secondStep` via e.g., `thenCompose`?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I added implementation of the internalAPI

Comment: As Slaw said, something like `foo1().thenCompose(x -> internalAPI(param -> { secondStep(); return Boolean.TRUE; });`, except that you have to check the boolean values if you keep using boolean values as success indicator, instead of using exceptions/failed futures.